# Why am I seeing unspecified sse errors using js server sent events with php?

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

I am setting up a system in which I use JS Server-Sent_Events with php.
And it works fine. But in every go around the error event gets triggered once and I cant understand why.

My JS:

```
var source = new EventSource("serverSideEvents.php");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
     var data =  $.parseJSON(event.data);
     $(data).each(function(){
            doSomethingWith(this); //works as expected
      });
};

source.onerror = function(event) {
   console.log(event); //fires every few seconds don't know why
};
```

My php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); 

  sendUpdates( );

function sendUpdates() {
  $controller = new someController();
  $out = $controller->Run();
  foreach($out as $msg)
    sendSSEMessage($msg['id'], 'data:'.json_encode($msg));
}

function sendSSEMessage( $id, $data ){
  echo "id: $id \n$data \n\n";
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}
```

This works ok, on the cli or browser the php throws no errors, yet the error event of js SSE fires every time the php is run. This is the error out in console:

```
Event {isTrusted: true, type: "error", target: EventSource, currentTarget: EventSource, eventPhase: 2, …}
bubbles:false
cancelBubble:false
cancelable:false
composed:false
currentTarget:
EventSource {url: "http://localhost:7790/serverSideEvents.php", withCredentials: false, readyState: 0, onopen: null, onmessage: ƒ, …}
defaultPrevented:false
eventPhase:0
isTrusted:true
path:[]
returnValue:true
srcElement:EventSource {url: "http://localhost:7790/serverSideEvents.php", withCredentials: false, readyState: 0, onopen: null, onmessage: ƒ, …}
target:EventSource {url: "http://localhost:7790/serverSideEvents.php", withCredentials: false, readyState: 0, onopen: null, onmessage: ƒ, …}
timeStamp:1129162.5250000001
type:"error"
__proto__:Event
```

To be clear: the code works as expected. I get the server messages I need. but also the error event is triggered.

Comment: maybe a CORS issue?

Comment: The Error occurs when the Server-side terminates (like it should).
You can either keep alive the server-side program for a few more seconds, or catch the error in JS and act on it or not - whatever seems good for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error usually occur due to server error and close connection, or when the connection is simply closed by the server (happens when the server script has finished),

i think the proper way would be to close the connection on the client side as well,

so in my client i am doing:

```
<script>
    // Open a new EventSource connection to the SSE server
    const eventSource = new EventSource('/My_SSE_URL');
                
    // Event listener for messages received from the SSE server
    eventSource.onmessage = function (event) {
        // Handle received event message
    };
    
    eventSource.onerror = function(error) {
        // Close the connection in case of an error
        eventSource.close(); // <---- This is what you want to do
    
        console.error('Error occurred:', error);
        // Handle the SSE connection error as needed
        // For example, you can display an error message to the user
    };
</script>
```